# Is it possible to inject into process without admin rights in Mac OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, inject

Is it possible to inject into application without admin rights in Mac OSX?

I have found one Library "https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject", which could be used but it needs admin rights.

Comment: Fortunately it's not possible!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, for obvious reasons.